# Python - Datetime conversation, matching .7930000Z?

Tags: python

Im trying to convert a date time into a human friendly format but keep getting errors in the conversion, im not what im missing to match the current format.

I think its 7930000Z thats causing the issue, everything else seems straight forward.

Ive tried, %fZ and %SZ, no luck thus far

```
>>> datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime('2017-09-18T21:20:33.7930000Z', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'),'%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2017-09-18T21:20:33.7930000Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'
```

Comment: `'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f0Z'`

Comment: @Goyo that did it!

Comment: Will fail if the last digit is not a 0 :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe %f is for microseconds and they are "Between 0 and 999999 inclusive"(https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

And a post about nanoseconds parsing: [Format Nanoseconds in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611328/format-nanoseconds-in-python)

Comment: Yes and you have 7 digits, not 6

Comment: ah I see, maybe the last end is timezone? should I just strip it?

Comment: either you strip last digit or if you are sure it is always a 0 you can use @Goyo format

Comment: ive just got rid of it all with re.sub(r'.\d*Z', '', '2017-09-18T21:20:33.7930000Z'), then converted after