# Strange behaviour when comparing Timestamp and datetime64 in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

Has anyone encountered similar cases as below, where if we let `a` be a `Timestamp`, `b` to be `datetime64`, then comparing `a < b` is fine, but `b < a` returns error.

If `a` can be compared to `b`, I thought we should be able to compare the other way around?

For example (Python 2.7):

```
>>> a
Timestamp('2013-03-24 05:32:00')
>>> b
numpy.datetime64('2013-03-23T05:33:00.000000000')
>>> a < b
False
>>> b < a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pandas\_libs\tslib.pyx", line 1080, in pandas._libs.tslib._Timestamp.__richcmp__ (pandas\_libs\tslib.c:20281)
TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'long'
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an interesting question. I've done some digging around and did my best to explain some of this, although one thing i still don't get is why we get `pandas` throwing an error instead of `numpy` when we do `b<a`.

Regards to your question:

> If a can be compared to b, I thought we should be able to compare the other way around?

That's not necesserily true. It just depends on the implementation of the comparison operators.

Take this test class for example:

```
class TestCom(int):
    def __init__(self, a):
    self.value = a

    def __gt__(self, other):
    print('TestComp __gt__ called')
    return True

    def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.a == other
```

Here I have defined my `__gt__` (`<`) method to always return true no matter what the other value is. While `__eq__` (`==`) left the same.

Now check the following comparisons out:

```
a = TestCom(9)
print(a)
# Output: 9

# my def of __ge__
a > 100

# Ouput: TestComp __gt__ called
# True

a > '100'
# Ouput: TestComp __gt__ called
# True

'100' < a

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-486-8aee1b1d2500> in <module>()
      1 # this will not use my def of __ge__
----> 2 '100' > a

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'TestCom'
```

So going back to your case.  Looking at the [timestamps_sourceCode](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cf70d11a25ec59a5b630921d86759c7fa49884db/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L123) the only thing i can think of is `pandas.Timestamp` does some type checking and conversion if possible.

When we're comparing a with b (`pd.Timestamp` against `np.datetime64`), `Timestamp.__richcmp__` function does the comparison, if it is of type `np.datetime64` then it converts it to `pd.Timestamp` type and does the comparison.

```
# we can do the following to have a comparison of say b > a
# this converts a to np.datetime64 - .asm8 is equivalent to .to_datetime64()
b > a.asm8

# or we can confert b to datetime64[ms]
b.astype('datetime64[ms]') > a

# or convert to timestamp
pd.to_datetime(b) > a
```

What i found surprising was, as i thought the issue is with `nanoseconds` not in Timestamp, is that even if you do the following the comparison between np.datetime64 with pd.Timestamp fails.

```
a = pd.Timestamp('2013-03-24 05:32:00.00000001')
a.nanosecond   # returns 10
# doing the comparison again where they're both ns still fails
b < a
```

Looking at the source code it seems like we can use `==` and `!=` operators. But even they dont work as expected. Take a look at the following for an example:

```
a = pd.Timestamp('2013-03-24 05:32:00.00000000')
b = np.datetime64('2013-03-24 05:32:00.00000000', 'ns')

b == a  # returns False

a == b  # returns True
```

I think this is the result of lines 149-152 or 163-166. Where they return `False` if your using `==` and `True` for `!=`, without actually comparing the values.

**Edit**:
The `nanosecond` feature was added in version `0.23.0`. So you can do something like `pd.Timestamp('2013-03-23T05:33:00.000000022', unit='ns')`. So yes when you compare `np.datetime64` it will be converted to `pd.Timestamp` with `ns` precision.

Just note that `pd.Timestamp` is supposed to be a replacement for python`s datetime:

> Timestamp is the pandas equivalent of python's Datetime
>       and is interchangeable with it in most cases.

But python's datetime doesn't support nanoseconds - good answer here explaining why [SO_Datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10612166/9202873).`pd.Timestamp` have support for comparison between the two even if your `Timestamp` has nanoseconds in it. When you compare a `datetime` object agains `pd.Timestamp` object with `ns` they have [_compare_outside_nanorange](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/cf70d11a25ec59a5b630921d86759c7fa49884db/pandas/_libs/tslibs/timestamps.pyx#L204) that will do the comparison.

Going back to `np.datetime64`, one thing to note here as explained nicely in this post [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49758140/9202873) is that *it's a wrapper on an `int64` type*. So not suprising if i do the following:

```
1 > a
a > 1
```

Both will though an error `Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'`.

So under the hood when you do `b > a` the comparison most be done on an `int` level, this comparison will be done by `np.greater()` function [np.greater](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.greater.html) - also take a look at [ufunc_docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/ufuncs.html#ufuncs-kwargs).

> **Note**: I'm unable to confirm this, the numpy docs are too complex to go through. If any numpy experts can comment on this, that'll be helpful.

If this is the case, if the comparison of `np.datetime64` is based on `int`, then the example above with `a == b` and `b == a` makes sense. Since when we do `b == a` we compare the `int` value of `b` against `pd.Timestamp` this will always return `Flase` for `==` and `True` for `!=`.

Its the same as doing say `123 == '123'`, this operation will not fail, it will just return `False`.

Comment: Many thanks gyx-hh! Your answer explains much of my "misunderstanding on <,>,== operator"! Back to the nanoseconds issue, so there seems to be a "feature" on the compatibility of np.datetime64 and pd.Timestamp? I'm just a bit shocked upon seeing the result of your "a== b, b == a" code block...

Comment: @Min I've just updated my answer with some extra info

Comment: Thanks a lot! Much appreciated for your answer!