# How to convert 12 hour string into 24 hour datetime?

Tags: python, datetime, time, strptime

I've seen solutions for converting something like `'7:30 PM'` using the `datetime.strptime` format `'%I:%M%p'` (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)), but I have strings that look like this:

```
'05:15:00.000000000 AM'
```

The fact that there are both seconds and AM/PM seems to be uncommon.

How can I convert this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem with your format is that Python does not support anything more granular than microseconds, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10612166/1326534). In fact, assuming you have 000 as the last three decimals of seconds, you can use the format below.

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('24/NOV/18 05:15:00.000000000 AM', '%d/%b/%y %I:%M:%S.%f000 %p')
```

If you cannot make that assumption, this dirty hack should work:

```
from datetime import datetime
s = '24/NOV/18 05:15:00.000000000 AM'
s = s[:-9] + s[-6:]
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(s, '%d/%b/%y %I:%M:%S.%f %p')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parser` from `dateutil` package to convert string into a datetime object, then use datetime object to get string from it.

```
from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime
dt = parser.parse("'24/NOV/18 05:15:00.000000000 AM'")
print(dt)
datetime_object = datetime.strftime(dt, '%b %d %Y %I:%M%p')
print(datetime_object)
```

Outputs:

```
2018-11-24 05:15:00 # parser output
Nov 24 2018 05:15AM # strftime output
```