# Why am I getting unconverted data error when using strptime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, strptime

I am converting `'12:37:00.60735106'` to a time object to get the difference.

```
 line[1] = '12:37:00.60735106'
 t1 = time.strptime(line[1], "%H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Error `ValueError: unconverted data remains: 06`

If I remove the last two digits it works. What am I missing?

When I drop off the last two digits.

```
line[1] = '12:37:00.607351'
t1 = time.strptime(line[1], "%H:%M:%S.%f")
prints 12:38:00.60734606
```

Which is longer than my original.

Comment: Because `%f` does *micro*seconds, up to 6 decimal places, per [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

Comment: So dropping down to only 6 digits is the only way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing datetime strings containing nanoseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611328/parsing-datetime-strings-containing-nanoseconds)