# Is there a way to have a timestamp set to your own reference timeframe? Such as the clock starting from 01/01/2000?

Tags: python, timestamp

I need to create a timestamp that follows the same notation as a regular timestamp except it's reference time starts from 01/01/2000 being time zero.

Comment: And what difficulty are you having?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: doesn`t seems to have difficult. Just use current time minus that time. There yo have it. See ros time implmentaion. they count from 1970 i think

Comment: Tell us your current situation carolineodeluce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume a "regular timestamp" should be seconds since?

```
import datetime
(datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
```

Comment: Yeah that works! How would I get nanoseconds with this as well?

Comment: The solution provides milliseconds precision. datetime does not support more than this, as do obviously most OS and hardware platforms AFAIK. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10612166/1522205