# How to add seconds (mili, nano, micro) to T/Z (ISO 8601) timestamp format?

Tags: python, datetime

Basically I have an entire dataframe with the timestamp in the following format:
2018-01-17T05:00:00.000000Z

And I'm looking to add different seconds on it (sometimes add 1 second, sometimes add 1 microsecond, etc).

Comment: `your_date + datetime.timedelta(microseconds=1)`

Comment: The timestamp unfortunately is in str format. How would I convert to datetime? Then my guess is your code would work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python `datetime` allows you to use milliseconds and microseconds.

```
>>> from datetime import datetime,timedelta
>>> dt = datetime.now()
>>> print(dt)
2019-07-05 17:21:49.523664
>>> dt1 = dt + timedelta(microseconds = 1,milliseconds = 1)
>>> print(dt1)
2019-07-05 17:21:49.524665
```

Regarding the nanoseconds you can find information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611328/parsing-datetime-strings-containing-nanoseconds).

In case you have it as a `string` you have to transform it into `datetime`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime,timedelta
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> date = dateutil.parser.parse("2018-01-17T05:00:00.000000Z")
>>> print(date)
2018-01-17 05:00:00+00:00
>>> dt1 = date + timedelta(microseconds = 1,milliseconds = 1)
>>> print(dt1)
2018-01-17 05:00:00.001001+00:00
```

If you ask for the last part of the date `+00:00`, it is for the time zone you can remove it like this:

```
>>> dt1 = dt1.replace(tzinfo=None)
>>> print(dt1)
2018-01-17 05:00:00.001001
```

Answer (score 0):

With [Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat) you may use `datetime.fromisoformat`:

```
import datetime
value = datetime.datetime.fromisoformat(str)
value += datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
```

With older Python version you may use:

```
import datetime    
value = datetime.datetime.strptime(str, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
value += datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
```