# Python datetime specify amount of milliseconds after the decimal point

Tags: python, datetime, iso

I have a string of time that looks like this: "2022-02-16T14:33:25.943971072". I tried to convert it to a datetime object with this format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f', but it doesn't work because it expects to get 6 digits of milliseconds.

What should be the format to convert the string to datetime?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parsing datetime strings containing nanoseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611328/parsing-datetime-strings-containing-nanoseconds)

Comment: @buran I decided to slice the last three digits as one of the answers suggested. It seems that I anyway would need to slice them out

Comment: That's always a possible approach.

Comment: [pandas datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) allows you to keep the nanoseconds, as it uses nanosecond precision.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass inputting the format and change the string to a datetime object without knowing the format, you can simply use `dateutil` and `parser`:

```py
from dateutil import parser
parser.parse("2022-02-16T14:33:25.943971072")
```

##### Output

```
datetime.datetime(2022, 2, 16, 14, 33, 25, 943971)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong datetime doesn't support in more than 6 digits in the millisecond part.
I liked the suggestion of @Amirhossein Kiani above, I believe a simpler solution is just slicing the string:

```py
datetime.datetime.strptime"2022-02-16T14:33:25.943971072")[:-3], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

There maybe a more elegant wat to slice it but it works