# which string format is used to be able to get nanoseconds

Tags: python

I want to be able to get 10 digits after the period in the seconds. i want to be able to have something as follows:

```
14-07-2002 10:40:20.xxxxxxxxxx
```

how can i modify the below posted line of code to achieve that please?

**code**:

```
return datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f)")
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611328/parsing-datetime-strings-containing-nanoseconds

Comment: just pad the right hand side with zeros, e.g. `datetime.now().strftime("%d-%b-%Y (%H:%M:%S.%f0000)")`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [time.time_ns()](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.time_ns)

```
import time
from datetime import datetime

nanos = time.time_ns()
secs = nanos / 1e9

dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(nanos / 1e9)
timeWithNS = '{}{:03.0f}'.format(dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'), nanos % 1e3)
print(timeWithNS)
# 2022-07-14 11:30:26.059128064
```

Although this may be somewhat limited because your hardware / OS may not fully support nanoseconds

Comment: yes, but that will provide a value like a timepstame since the last epoch. i want to have 10 digits after the poriod in the seconds value

Comment: Just updated my answer - hopefully this answers your question more fully