# how to get nano seconds timestamp in python 3.6?

Tags: python, timestamp

I need to send a nanoseconds timestamp to influx db (1.2).

Maybe you could recommend the simple way in python 3.6 to convert current date time to nanoseconds timestamp ?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get POSIX/Unix time in seconds and nanoseconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394485/get-posix-unix-time-in-seconds-and-nanoseconds-in-python)

Comment: How can you trust that the nano-second value is correct when you have a lot of cores? What are you going to do, take the nano-second value of a function that runs at micro-second intervals? No program will run at Nano second level, only the hardware can go to that level.

Comment: also: If you've got a nano-second level DB entry have proplem very serious. In buffer memory: "can not write last value as initial value (what is array)?"

Comment: thank you, did it in simple way. Just took builtin timestamp function and converterted it to NS (x100000000).