# How to get timestamp in nanoseconds in Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, timestamp, influxdb, epoch

```
import time
print(time.time())
```

This gives me output:

```
1590683242.8507078
```

Desired output is 19-digit long nanosecond Unix timestamp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get POSIX/Unix time in seconds and nanoseconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394485/get-posix-unix-time-in-seconds-and-nanoseconds-in-python)

Comment: Yup, Thanks for the ref

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```py
import time
print(time.time_ns())
```

Comment: this need python >= 3.7

Answer (score 2):

```py
import time
print(time.time_ns())
```

```
1590683731073953000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use time.time_ns() method of Time module.

```
import time
print(time.time_ns())
```

- time.time() -- retrieves time in seconds.
- time.time_ns() -- retrieves time in nano seconds.

Comment: It shows "time has no attribute time_ns()

Comment: Have you imported the time module like this, or have you accidentally imported the time function from time module ?

Comment: Upgrading from python3.6 to 3.7 worked. Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

`time.time_ns()`

Similar to time() but returns time as an integer number of nanoseconds since the epoch.

See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/time.html#time.time_ns

Comment: My python was version 3.6. Thanks !