# Get Epoch Timestamp in Nanoseconds in Python 3.6.9

Tags: python, timestamp, python-3.6, epoch

In Python 3.7, `time_ns()` gives epoch timestamp in nanoseconds. How can it be got in 3.6.9?
When I use `time()`, it gives me seconds.

Comment: That should be resolvable with simple math.

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394485/get-posix-unix-time-in-seconds-and-nanoseconds-in-python

Comment: `time()` returns a floating point number, so it is much more precise than seconds. You just need to multiply it.

Answer (score -2):

You can't get nanosecond accuracy even using time_ns(). It's better than time(), but still not real nano-second accuracy.

Take a look at PEP-564 (https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0564/#annex-clocks-resolution-in-python) - maybe you can just multiply by 1e9 and get a satisfactory result.

Comment: `time()` and `time_ns()` are using the same underlying function to get the time. The only difference is that one returns a floating point and the other returns an integer. The precision (of both of them) depends on the operating system.

Comment: The link that I posted contains a resolution analysis. I suppose you didn't open it, so here is the summary:

"The resolution of time.time_ns() is much better than time.time(): 84 ns (2.8x better) vs 239 ns on Linux and 318 us (2.8x better) vs 894 us on Windows."