# How can I take one nanosecond away from a datetime timestamp, and have the final form in datetime timestamp?

Tags: python, timestamp

I have a datetime timestamp of `2022-10-11 06:00:00`.

I am trying to take away ONE nanosecond and have it back in datetime format. So the desired output is:

```
`2022-10-11 05:59:59.999999999`
```

I have followed a few functions and conversions on stack overflow, but most don't get the precision correct. They convert the datetime into nanoseconds, take one away then convert it back, but then one hour is somehow added because of precision (or lack of precision)

Any help would be great!

Comment: That's not one nanosecond less, that's 10 microseconds less.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592).

Comment: Datetime doesn't go down to nanoseconds, microseconds is as low as it goes.

Comment: Sorry let me edit the question, I do mean nanosecond!

Comment: There, it is correct now!

Comment: So there's no way to convert it?

Comment: It's still not one nanosecond less, that would be `2022-10-11 05:59:59.999999999`

Comment: Changed- I do mean one nanosecond, sorry

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get POSIX/Unix time in seconds and nanoseconds in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394485/get-posix-unix-time-in-seconds-and-nanoseconds-in-python)

Comment: How does it work, you pass in the time as an argument into`time.time_ns()`?

Comment: OK I see what it does, but how does it help me?? - I'm trying to take one nanosecond off.

Comment: It doesn't help you. The combination of datetime and nanoseconds simply can't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

datetime.datetime only supports till microsecond precision.
If you need nanosecond precision, use pandas.Timestamp instead.

```py
import pandas as pd
import time

now_in_ns = pd.Timestamp(time.time_ns(), unit='ns')
one_ns_later = now_in_ns + pd.Timedelta('1ns')

print(now_in_ns, one_ns_later)
```

So, if you are going to be working with nanoseconds, either extend datetime.datetime to support nanosecond or familiarize yourself with the class: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html