# Equivalent to GetTickCount() on Linux

Tags: python, c, linux, time

I'm looking for an equivalent to [`GetTickCount()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408%28VS.85%29.aspx) on Linux.

Presently I am using Python's [`time.time()`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.time) which presumably calls through to [`gettimeofday()`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/gettimeofday.2.html). My concern is that the time returned (the unix epoch), may change erratically if the clock is messed with, such as by NTP. A simple process or system wall time, that only increases positively at a constant rate would suffice.

Does any such time function in C or Python exist?

Comment: related: [How do I get monotonic time durations in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1205722/4279)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use [CLOCK_MONOTONIC](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/clock_getres.html) e.g. in C:

```
struct timespec ts;
if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts) != 0) {
 //error
}
```

See this question for a Python way - [How do I get monotonic time durations in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205722/how-do-i-get-monotonic-time-durations-in-python)

Comment: And on very old Linux systems you can use /proc/uptime as a monotonic time source. Clunky but works.

Comment: There's a note on the manpage: `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` (since Linux 2.6.28; Linux-specific)
              Similar to `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`, but provides access to a  raw  hard‐
              ware-based time that is not subject to NTP adjustments. Does this mean that `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` is more appropriate?

Comment: @MattJoiner: When `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` talks about NTP adjustments, it is referring to the *rate* of the clock rather than the absolute value.  `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` will not skip (as the name implies), and is usually the correct choice.

Comment: It might be worth checking out this question about CLOCK_MONOTONIC: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657289/linux-clock-gettimeclock-monotonic-strange-non-monotonic-behavior

Answer (score 8):

This seems to work:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

uint32_t getTick() {
    struct timespec ts;
    unsigned theTick = 0U;
    clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts );
    theTick  = ts.tv_nsec / 1000000;
    theTick += ts.tv_sec * 1000;
    return theTick;
}
```

yes, get_tick()
Is the backbone of my applications.
Consisting of one state machine for each 'task'
eg, can multi-task without using threads and Inter Process Communication
Can implement non-blocking delays.

Answer (score 6):

You should use: `clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &tp);`. This call is not affected by the adjustment of the system time just like GetTickCount() on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the kernel has high-resolution timers but it is differently.  I would recommend that you look at the sources of any odd project that wraps this in a portable manner.

From C/C++ I usually `#ifdef` this and use `gettimeofday()` on Linux which gives me microsecond resolution. I often add this as a fraction to the seconds since epoch I also receive giving me a double.