# What is the Linux version of GetTickCount?

Tags: linux, winapi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Equivalent to GetTickCount() on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958291/equivalent-to-gettickcount-on-linux)

What is the Linux version of GetTickCount?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958291/equivalent-to-gettickcount-on-linux