# linux - print current time with microsecond precision on multi-processor system

Tags: c++, linux

How can I print current system time with microsecond (or, better, nanosecond) precision? I need this time to be consistent between all system processors. If this is not possible than I want it to be consistent between all processor cores.

I've tried `clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME` but I suspect it produce different result at least when running on different processors.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833094/get-a-timestamp-in-c-in-microseconds).

Comment: Take a look at [`std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)

Comment: if high_resolution_clock works accross different phissical procesors?

Comment: what is better feets low-latency requirements - high_resulution_clock or clock_gettime or gettimeofday ?

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me what you really want is `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW` (or just `CLOCK_MONOTONIC`) . The raw clock measures time starting at a fixed point and queries a pure hardware-based clock. On Linux this fixed time point is the time of startup. Changes in the system time do not effect this clock (Summer/wintertime, etc.)

You can check the resolution of the clock in your system with a call to `clock_getres(clockid_t clk_id, struct timespec *res);`

Both `gettime` and `getres` take a timespec structure which holds two integers: seconds and nanoseconds. So the software is there, you just need a (hardware) clock capable of supplying the nanosecond resolution.

Man pages of the two functions:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html & 
http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime

If you have access to the book "Linux Programming Interface" by Michael Kerrisk check out chapter 23 paragraph 5 (POSIX Clocks). When it comes to basic Linux programming this book has given me more answers than even StackOverflow has!

Comment: Even more important is reading [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Comment: is it guaranteed that CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW can be used across physical processors?

Comment: The monotonic clock is for the system. So, the way I read it is that no matter how many cores you have the time will be the same across all of them.
It is answered in this SO question too: [Is clock monotonic process or thread specific.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943733/is-clock-monotonic-process-or-thread-specific).