# clock_gettime returns some extrange values

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to profile a program with this class:

```
namespace smtx{
    class CPerformance_clock
    {
        timespec t1;

        timespec diff(timespec start, timespec end)
        {
            timespec temp;
            if ((end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec)<0) {
                temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec-1;
                temp.tv_nsec = 1000000000+end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
            } else {
                temp.tv_sec = end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec;
                temp.tv_nsec = end.tv_nsec-start.tv_nsec;
            }
            return temp;
        }

    public :
        CPerformance_clock(){}
        /**
         * Starts the clock by taking the initial measure
         */
        void start()
        {
            assert(clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&t1) == 0);
        }
        long int getElapsedTime()
        {
            timespec t2, final;
            assert (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&t2) == 0);
            final = diff(t1, t2);
            return (final.tv_sec * 1000000000) + final.tv_nsec;

        }

        void restart()
        {
            clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&t1);
        }
    };
};
```

I control min, max and average time, with this code

```
if(t > max_time)
{
    max_time = t;
}
if(t < min_time)
{
    min_time = t;
}
++count_time;
sum_time += t;
chunk_sum_time +=t;
++chunk_count_time;
```

Nothing extraordinary at all.
But when I execute the program, the max time allways have a extrange time value:
Min time: 831 ns at 40784 , Max_time: 9773850 ns at 1123
The max time is far long that the total execution time, so I don't understand this. I do not make any conversion o division in the process of display data, to don't lose data.

I've readed this post, [Linux clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC) strange non-monotonic behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657289/linux-clock-gettimeclock-monotonic-strange-non-monotonic-behavior) , but my kernel is newest, though is an ubuntu too.

To finish, I made test with CLOCK_MONOTONIC, CLOCK_REALTIME, CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW, and nothing solves this issue.

Also, I'm not sure that this matters but I'm programming and executing this program on a virtual machine.

Some help?

EDIT: To put an example of my problem: I process 4.000.000 of results in about 60 seconds. The average time of each result is 4000 nano seconds. An strange error could be 14 seconds, but the program run smooth and in any moment stops for 14 seconds.

In executions of 500.000 results (execued in 3 seconds) I get similar MAX_TIMEs, like 9 seconds.

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe it's simply a scheduler issue?

Comment: Scheduler? What is this?

Comment: you know, the OS pauses your process and gives a chance to an other process to run.. What happens if you use `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`?

Comment: But I think it cannot be possible: the whole program last for 3 seconds and I get measures of 9 seconds for a simple function call. There are no little differences

Comment: Did you maybe forget to initialize max_time to `0` or some other sensible value?

Comment: Did you initialize max_time to zero?

Comment: Sidenote: You can just use the standard library for finding a maximum/minimum - `maximum = std::max(maximum, t);`

Comment: @yi_H You're right!!! But this is one of my last executions: Processed 4050000 entries so far
Min time: 783 ns at 31 , Max_time: 1245138860 ns at 3862063
Average time: 682 ns for 4049843 results
Chunk Average time: 18462 ns for 50000 results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fluctuation is caused by the OS scheduler. It pauses your process and gives a chance to an other process to run.

Can you report back results with `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID`?

Comment: Processed 4100000 entries so far
Min time: 0 ns at 9899 , Max_time: 4814392 ns at 368618
Average time: 522 ns for 4099842 results
Chunk Average time: 2796 ns for 49999 results
It seems much better