# Understanding the different clocks of clock_gettime()

Tags: c++, c, clock

Hi I wanted to use the `clock_gettime()` function for measuring the performance of my code.

I am unable to understand the difference between the different kinds of clocks used in the function from the man page descriptions. esp

```
CLOCK_REALTIME,

CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID

CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID
```

Can someone explaing what each of these clocks do?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12392278/measure-time-in-linux-time-vs-clock-vs-getrusage-vs-clock-gettime-vs-gettimeof

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`CLOCK_REALTIME` reports the actual wall clock time.

`CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is for measuring relative real time. It advances at the same rate as the actual flow of time but it's not subject to discontinuities from manual or automatic (NTP) adjustments to the system clock.

`CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` is for measuring the amount of CPU time consumed by the process.

`CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` is for measuring the amount of CPU time consumed by the thread. It's supported by modern kernels and glibc  since 2.6.12, but on older linux kernels glibc emulates it badly by simply returning the amount of CPU time consumed by the *process* since the moment the thread was created.

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html

Comment: So should the speed of an implemented algorithm be measured by CLOCK_REALTIME or by CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID?

Comment: It depends on what you want to measure. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` should be used if you want to measure total elapsed time, including time spent blocked waiting for IO, but it will also include slowdowns caused by other processes getting scheduled while your program is trying to run. `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` will only count actual clock cycles spent executing on your process's behalf (in either userspace or kernelspace, I believe), but not any time spent blocked/sleeping.

Comment: Note that CLOCK_MONOTONIC is subject to discontinuities from system time adjustment in Linux.  CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW was defined to get around this.

Comment: @BDatRivenhill: I believe you're mistaken. `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is subject to running fast or slow due to smooth clock adjustment (e.g. by ntpd), but it will never be discontinuous.

Comment: I would tend to think BDat us correct? See <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657289/linux-clock-gettimeclock-monotonic-strange-non-monotonic-behavior> which recommends using CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW for game loops because of possibilty of CLOCK_MONOTONIC jumping backward.

Comment: @ScrollerBlaster: I've actually been searching for information on this issue and can't find anything reliable. Certainly the *intent* of `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` on Linux is that it actually be monotonic and only subject to continuous adjustments for clock skew, not discontinuous clock changes, but a number of people claim there are bugs. Do you have any authoritative sources? Should I open a new question on the matter?

Comment: @R I'm afraid I have nothing authoritative yet. I am trolling through many questions. I'm looking for the ideal thing to use in my game loop. If it can adjust based on periodic updates from the server time then that would be bad, no? Perhaps a question specifically for gamers.

Comment: I don't think it's at all gamer-specific. If `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` is broken the way some people say it is, then it should absolutely never be used and the kernel should just remap it to match `CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW`. This is why I'm skeptical of claims that it's that broken...

Comment: (I added a note to the link from @ScrollerBlaster.)  My understanding is that "raw" is the internal clock, which isn't always spot on (like a clock that runs a bit too fast or too slow).  The NTP daemon applies an adjustment to make the clock run at exactly the right speed.  So if you want to measure according to the actual passage of time, CLOCK_MONOTONIC should be more accurate.  OTOH, for a given machine, CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW is more likely to be consistent between runs.  Consistently inaccurate, but consistent. :-)

Comment: According to [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html), CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID is implemented in Linux kernel since 2.6.12 and glibc 2.4+ natively supports it.