# C++ timer in microseconds

Tags: c++, time, timer

I am trying to do a timer in microseconds, but it's not quite working.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    struct timespec start_time;
    struct timespec end_time;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &start_time);
    usleep(5000);
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &end_time);
    cout << "START: " << (start_time.tv_nsec/1000) << endl;
    cout << "END: " << (end_time.tv_nsec/1000) << endl;
    cout << "DIFF: " << (end_time.tv_nsec - start_time.tv_nsec) /1000 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The result look like this:

```
START: 3586
END: 3630
DIFF: 43
```

I need the DIFF be around 5000. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's a standard `<chrono>` header. No need for platform-specific code.

Comment: @chris: Only since C++11, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to measure, but I guess `CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID` is the wrong timer, you likely want `CLOCK_MONOTONIC` if you want to measure some elapsed time. Have a look at a [similar stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506952/understanding-the-different-clocks-of-clock-gettime) that shows the difference between the different clocks of `clock_gettime`.

That said, to get the full time you have to add `tv_sec` and `tv_nsec` (of course first converting `tv_sec` to nano seconds) of each measurement and then subtract that total, so something like:

```
uint64_t startNs = start_time.tv_sec * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 + start_time.tv_nsec;
uint64_t endNs = end_time.tv_sec * 1000 * 1000 * 1000 + end_time.tv_nsec;
uint64_t diffNs = endNs - startNs;
uint64_t diffMicro = diffNs / 1000;
```

And if you're on C++11, probably best use some [high level class](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock/now) from the chrono namespace.

Comment: I think that you may be in the realms of overflow. That is the reason why the structure has two parts

Answer (score 1):

Two things.

1. Guess you need CLOCK_REALTIME
2. There are two components of `timespec` - need to take both into account when doing the subtraction

Answer (score 1):

try with 
clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &start)
clock_gettime( CLOCK_REALTIME, &stop)

You need to use 'tv_sec' part of the timespec  structure as well.

Time = ((stop.tv_sec - start.tv_sec)+ (double)(stop.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)/1e9)*1000;//im ms