# Time spends in CPU faster than in reality

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cpu, ctime

I am wondering why my entire application runs in less than `8 seconds` while the time obtained from `clock_gettime` is `19.3468 seconds` which is more than two times as much as what happens in reality. Where is the problem from?

```
clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time_start);

... // many calculations

clock_gettime(CLOCK_PROCESS_CPUTIME_ID, &time_stop);
double time_diff=(time_stop.tv_sec-time_start.tv_sec+
    (1e-9)*(time_stop.tv_nsec-time_start.tv_nsec);
```

---

**Update:**

I am not using any OpenMP explicitly.

Comment: Related: [Understanding the different clocks of clock_gettime()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7506952/understanding-the-different-clocks-of-clock-gettime)

Comment: @dxiv but process time is always less than wall time not more.

Comment: You are asking about CPU time. Think multiple CPUs.

Comment: @dxiv do you mean multiple cores? i am not using openMP

Comment: The `// many calculations` block may be executing on multiple threads, and be using multiple CPUs/cores, even without explicitly using openMP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**CLOCK_MONOTONIC** should be used if you want to measure total elapsed time, including time spent blocked waiting for IO, but it will also include slowdowns caused by other processes getting scheduled while your program is trying to run.