# clock_monotonic_raw alternative in linux versions older than 2.6.28

Tags: linux, time

clock_monotonic_raw is only supported as of Linux 2.6.28.

is there another way i can get a monotonic time which isn't subject to NTP adjustments or the incremental adjustments performed by adjtime?
i can't use clock_monotonic since it's affected by NTP & adjtime.

Answer (score 2):

Take a closer look at CLOCK_MONOTONIC instead of just CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW.  I wanted to use CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW with condition waits, but found that it was not supported (Fedora 25/Linux 4.10.17).

The situation is vaguely infuriating, but the upshot on Linux, to the best of my current understanding, is:

1. CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW is the closest you are going to get to a square-wave accumulator running at constant frequency.  However, this is well-suited to less than you might think.
2. CLOCK_MONOTONIC is based on CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW with some gradual frequency corrections applied that allow it to eventually overtake or fall behind some other clock reference.  NTP and adjtime can both make these corrections.  However, to avoid doing things like breaking the hell out of software builds, the clock is *still guaranteed to monotonically advance*:

*"The adjustment that adjtime() makes to the clock is carried out in such a manner that the clock is always monotonically increasing."*
*--adjtime man page*

*"You lying bastard." --me*

3. Yup-- that was the plan, but bugs exist in kernel versions before 2.6.32.19; see discussion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3657433/3005946 which includes a link to a patch, if that affects you.  It's hard for me to tell what the maximum error from that bug is (and I'd really, really like to know).
4. Even in the 4.x kernel, most POSIX synchronization objects don't seem to support CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW or CLOCK_MONOTONIC_COARSE.  I have found this out the hard way.  ALWAYS error-check your *_setclock calls.
5. POSIX semaphores (sem_t) don't support ANY monotonic clocks at all, which is infuriating.  If you need this, you will have to roll your own using condition-waits.  (As a bonus, doing this will allow you to have semaphores with negative initial levels, which can be handy.)
6. If you're just trying to keep a synchronization object's wait-function from deadlocking forever, and you've got something like a three-second bailout, you can just use CLOCK_MONOTONIC and call it a day-- the adjustments CLOCK_MONOTONIC is subject to are, effectively, jitter correction, well-below your accuracy requirements.  Even in the buggy implementations, CLOCK_MONOTONIC is not going to jump backwards an hour or something like that.  Again, what happens instead is that things like adjtime tweak the frequency of the clock, so that it gradually overtakes, or falls behind, some other, parallel-running clock.
7. CLOCK_REALTIME is in fact CLOCK_MONOTONIC with some other correction factors applied.  Or the other way around.  Whatever, it's effectively the same thing.  The important part is that, if there is any chance your application will change time zones (moving vehicle, aircraft, ship, cruise missile, rollerblading cyborg) or encounter *administrative* clock adjustments, you should definitely NOT use CLOCK_REALTIME, or anything that requires it.  Same thing if the server uses daylight savings time instead of UTC.  However, a stationary server using UTC may be able to get away with CLOCK_REALTIME for coarse deadlock-avoidance purposes, if necessary. Avoid this unless you are on a pre-2.6 kernel and have no choice, though.
8. CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW is NOT something you want to use for timestamping.  It has not been jitter-corrected yet, etc.  It may be appropriate for DACs and ADCs, etc., but is not what you want to use for logging events on human-discernible time scales.  We have NTP for a reason.

Hope this is helpful, and I can certainly understand the frustration.