# Retrieve wall-time in Python using the standard library?

Tags: python, time, clock, standard-library, wall-time

How can I retrieve [wall-time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time) in Python using the standard library?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958291/equivalent-to-gettickcount-on-linux) question, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657289/linux-clock-gettimeclock-monotonic-strange-non-monotonic-behavior) question would suggest that something like [`clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime) or [`/proc/uptime`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) are most appropriate on Linux. On Windows, [`time.clock()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/time.html#time.clock) has the desired effect.

I would use [`time.time()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/time.html#time.time), but the function is not guaranteed to return [monotonically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) (and linearly) increasing time values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Victor Stinner wrote [a Python implementation of a monotonic timer](http://bugs.python.org/file19461/monotonic.py). See http://bugs.python.org/issue10278 for the discussion and [the docs for the upcoming 3.3 release](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/time.html#time.monotonic) referencing the new feature (coded in C).

There is also [Monoclock](https://github.com/ludios/Monoclock):

> Monoclock is a Python module that
>   provides access to the monotonic clock
>   on POSIX-like OSes that have `librt`.
>
> Compatibility: tested on CPython
>   2.6.5, CPython 2.7, pypy 1.3, and pypy 1.4.

Comment: Great work. It looks like clock_gettime and friends will be exposed in 3.3, as well as monotonic clocks used where appropriate for internal Python time-related stuff.