# Convert GetTickCount() vxWorks to Linux

Tags: c++, linux, vxworks

I am porting some vxWorks code to Linux.

I looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958291/equivalent-to-gettickcount-on-linux/2958359#2958359) and it recommends [CLOCK_MONOTONIC](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/clock_getres.html). Is that a suitable replacement for the following define:

```
#define GetTickCount()    ((1000.0 * (double)tickGet())/((double)sysClkRateGet())))
```

?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[GetTickCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is a windows API described thus:

> Retrieves the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started, up to 49.7 days

Yes, [CLOCK_MONOTONIC](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html) is the correct POSIX clock to use. Here is untested code for you:

```
double GetTickCount(void) 
{
  struct timespec now;
  if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &now))
    return 0;
  return now.tv_sec * 1000.0 + now.tv_nsec / 1000000.0;
}
```