# Time measure without using system clock

Tags: c++, linux, time, measure, elapsedtime

Is there any way to measure elapsed time in linux/unix without using system clock?
The problem is that system clock changes in some situations and elapsed time measured by `time` or `gettimeofday` or anything else like that gives incorrect result.

I'm thinking of creating separate thread which performs loop with `sleep(100)` inside and counts number of repetitions.

Any better solutions?

Comment: "performs loop with `sleep(100)` inside and counts number of repetitions". `sleep` is allowed to return late for no reason (well, no reason that your process can see), so that doesn't necessarily work.

Comment: And on what basis do you say time and gettimeofday are inaccurate?

Comment: From `man gettimeofday` - The time is expressed in **seconds** and **microseconds** since midnight (0 hour), January 1, 1970.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use monotonic time, which represents time since some point: http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime

```
int64_t get_monotonic_timestamp(void)
{
    struct timespec ts;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);
    return (int64_t)ts.tv_sec * 1000000 + ts.tv_nsec / 1000;
}
```

Comment: Or even better `CLOCK_BOOTTIME`.

Comment: I was going to say basically the same thing; the question is already answered in a similar question, http://stackoverflow.com/a/2958359/2696854

Answer (score 6):

[std::chrono::steady_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) can be used to measure time, and takes into account changes to the system clock.

Comment: To add to this answer, for sleeping there is [`sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) and [`sleep_until`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until).

Comment: Looks like a great solution to the problem, but looks like it's not yet supported by the gcc version we use.

Answer (score 2):

Measuring elapsed time with `sleep` (or variants) is a bad idea. Your thread can wake up at any time after the elapsed sleep time so this is sure to be inaccurate.

Comment: I don't need it to be very accurate, but when system time changes I get thousands of hours as elapsed time instead of couple of seconds.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. You reject the solution offered in the question, but haven't offered any other solution of your own.

Answer (score 1):

For a time delay, you can use e.g. [`select`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/select).