# Is there any C++ standard class/function which is similar to GetTickCount() on Windows?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, c++-chrono, gettickcount

```
unsigned int Tick = GetTickCount();
```

This code is running only on Windows, but I want to use the C++ Standard library so it can run elsewhere.

I searched `std::chrono`, but I can't find a function like `GetTickCount()`.

Do you know what I should use from `std::chrono`?

Comment: Nothing to get the number of milliseconds since the system was started that I know of, but lots for relative times.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2958291/256138

Comment: C++ doesn't have a notion of "the system started", so, no, there's nothing like it. There are plenty of things in `chrono` that might solve the same problem you're facing, though. We just need to know what problem you are facing.

Comment: @rubenvb: `clock_getttime()` is a POSIX standard interface, which isn't portable to Windows any more than `GetTickCount()` is portable to Linux, so the proposed duplicate is more 'related' than a duplicate.

Comment: `steady_clock` is the nearest equivalent, if you want the elapsed time between two arbitrary points - unlike `system_clock` it won't be adjusted. But it's no good if you specifically want the time since the system started; there's nothing standard for that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could build a custom `chrono` clock on top of Windows' `GetTickCount()`.  Then use that clock.  In porting, all you would have to do is port the clock.  For example, I am not on Windows, but here is what such a port might look like:

```
#include <chrono>

// simulation of Windows GetTickCount()
unsigned long long
GetTickCount()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}

// Clock built upon Windows GetTickCount()
struct TickCountClock
{
    typedef unsigned long long                       rep;
    typedef std::milli                               period;
    typedef std::chrono::duration<rep, period>       duration;
    typedef std::chrono::time_point<TickCountClock>  time_point;
    static const bool is_steady =                    true;

    static time_point now() noexcept
    {
        return time_point(duration(GetTickCount()));
    }
};

// Test TickCountClock

#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    auto t0 = TickCountClock::now();
    std::this_thread::sleep_until(t0 + std::chrono::seconds(1));
    auto t1 = TickCountClock::now();
    std::cout << (t1-t0).count() << "ms\n";
}
```

On my system, `steady_clock` happens to return nanoseconds since boot.  You may find other non-portable ways of emulating `GetTickCount()` on other platforms.  But once that detail is done, your clock is solid, and the clock's clients don't need to be any wiser about it.

For me this test reliably outputs:

```
1000ms
```